# Too many connections Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2005, idisposable

I'm migrating a Foxpro to ASP.NET MVC Application.

Near to 70% of the logic is embedded in SqlServer Stored Procedures. for that reason we are using some of the procedures to update some tables (we don´t map SP, just call them  using SqlConnection with SqlDataReader, SqlCommand, SqlAddapter).

The problem is that many connections are opened on each call. The connection is closed for each call even that. when run sp_who tooo many connections appear to opened for the same user.

What is the current way to perform closing and Disposing of each connection?

It is possible to find an active connection and reuse it ?

The last try was:

```
SqlConnection.ClearAllpools();
```

But it doesn't take immediate effect.
We have a IDisposabel class connection that perform connections.
This are de close method:

```
public void close()
{
    SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
    //.ClearPool(BdTransCx);
    // SqlConnection.ClearPool(BdArchCx);

    if (ConectarArchivos) 
    {
        if (BdArchCx.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            BdArchCx.Close();
        }
    }
    if (BdArchCx.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        BdTransCx.Close();
    }
}
```

This method is called after each request.

Comment: Close the connection as soon as you're finished with it. Have a look at the [using-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). The connection-pool asssumes that the connection cannot be reused when you've not closed it. Keep in mind that closing is only a flag for the pool, actually the connection to the database keeps open so that it can be reused as soon as possible. If every connection in the pool is in use(open), the pool creates a new pohysical connection what is very expensive. Does it reach the MaxPoolSize(default 100), you're getting your exception.

Comment: Very tks. The close method you are talking about is SqlConnection.close() ? or must be : using-statement?

Comment: Assuming `BdArchCx` is a `SqlConnection`: `BdArchCx.Close()` in a finally block of a try/catch is similar to `using(var BdArchCx=new SqlConnection(conString)){}` because `using` will call `dispose` which closes the connection implicitely. It is good practise to dispose every object implementing `IDisposable` as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You should wrap your `SqlConnection` objects, and any `SqlCommand` objects in a `using` block](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/01/13/773.aspx).

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(commandString, cn))
    {
        cn.Open();
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

For more details, please see ["Your Friend the C# Using Statement."](http://www.w3enterprises.com/articles/using.aspx)

Comment: Tks for your quick answer.... That code means the connection is inmediatly disposed?

Comment: Yes. **But** You must consider Reader dispose in the same manner.

Answer (score 2):

Connections in .NET are pooled, so it's normal to see some connections that are still active in the database.

You should not try to kill the connection pool, this will just kill the performance. The reason that there is a pool is that it's *a lot* faster to reuse a connection than to establish a new connection each time.

Just make sure that you close each connection and each command correctly, so that they are returned to the pool. You can use `using` blocks to make sure that they are disposed correctly whatever happens:

```
using (SqlConnection connenction = ...) {
  using (SqlCommand command = ...) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Make sure to keep the Reader as well in the using Statement to avoid connection issue

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(commandString, cn))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (IDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should still call cn.Close(); This is faster than waiting for the object to be garbage collected.